# The check login still a hurdle

Tags: php

i still have a problem with my login page. the code that extracts information that we login with is the most complicated one. I have four fields in the login table in my database and they are,  it is like this:`id, username, password and usertype. i want if some one logs in to be directed to their level of privilege(using usertype) if the user is an administrator, they should be directed to the administrators page and not to a normal user's page. this code says :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\Learning\Checklogin.php  on line 65 which is at the end.it looks like this:

```
enter code here
<?php


       define(DOC_ROOT,dirname(__FILE__)); // To properly get the config.php file


       $username = $_POST['username']; //Set UserName
       $password = $_POST['password']; //Set Password
       $msg ='';


       if(isset($username, $password)) {


   ob_start();


  include(DOC_ROOT.'/config.php'); //Initiate the MySQL connection


// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($username);
$mypassword = stripslashes($password);
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $mypassword);

 //Selecting all from the table
 $sql="SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
  $result=mysqli_query($dbC, $sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
{

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     $type = $row['Type'];

    $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $mypassword;
      $_SESSION['Type'] = $type;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
   {

  // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
  $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);


   if($type == "Admin")
      {


      header("Location: Admin.php");

      }


      else if(type == "User")
     {
    header("Location: userpage.php");
    }


    else if($type!='Admin'or'User')
                    {
    //echo'The page can not be found';
    header("location:error1.html");

            }
     else echo'sorry';

     }
  exit();
   ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

…means that the file ended before PHP expected it to. Try checking that all of your opening braces have a corresponding close brace.

Comment: This! Error messages are our best friends. BTW, op just have unnecessary opening curly brace which bracing first `if` statement closure

Comment: Ok thanks so much! I have corrected the mistakes but whenever i try logging in it does not and brings the same page with no errors. what can i do?

Comment: @JuicyScripter i cant login still yet i have corrected all the mistakes. It takes me to the checklogin page yet its supposed to direct me to a different page depending on my usertype. What else can i do?

Answer (score 2):

remove extra opening brace after $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;.

Comment: You have also some php syntax errors on the page, so after remove extra brace, solve those errors to make your page running

Answer (score 1):

first error I see is here:

```
else if(type == "User")
     {
    header("Location: userpage.php");
    }
```

try `$type` instead of `type`

Comment: on second view I see even more errors ;)

Comment: While this is wrong this not a show-stopper. `type` will be parsed as constant and once not resolved as string "type". OP have problem on parse level, before script running.

Comment: so the moral of the story is: debug your code! :)))

Comment: Ok thanks so much! I have corrected the mistakes but whenever i try logging in it does not and brings the same page with no errors. what can i do?

Comment: you can't use "header("location: userpage.php");" - you need to provide the full url: http://www.domain.com/userpage.php

Comment: I think this part is also wrong `if($type!='Admin'or'User')
`, try `if($type != 'Admin' || $type != 'User')`